# AS3 - Merging XML Files

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, parsing

I'm creating a trivia game is Flash (AS3) with two different categories. The player can choose one category, or the other, or both categories together. In the code below I'm trying to merge the two xml files together into a new xml file if the person selects both categories. I'm getting an "Access of undefined property error for myLoader and myLoader2 and I don't know why.

```
// start loading of questions
public function xmlImport() 
{
    var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    var myLoader2:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

    if (so.data.question_set == "BOTH")
    {
        myLoader.load(new URLRequest("category1.xml"));
        myLoader2.load(new URLRequest("category2.xml"));
        myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadXML2);

        function loadXML2() 
        {
            myLoader2.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, combineXML);
        }
    }

    if (so.data.question_set == "ONE")
    {
        myLoader.load(new URLRequest("category1.xml"));
        myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);
    }

    if (so.data.question_set == "TWO")
    {
        myLoader.load(new URLRequest("category2.xml"));
        myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);
    }
}

public function combineXML() 
{
    var xmlJoin:XML = <trivia></trivia>;
    var i:XML;

    for each(i in myLoader)
    {
        xmlJoin.appendChild(i);
    }

    for each(i in myLoader2)
    {
        xmlJoin.appendChild(i);
    }

    trace(xmlJoin);
}
```

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Rich

Answer (score 0):

In the third option could you not have two loaders and when each completes, the result XML is appended to a previously defined empty XML value.

A rough example:

```
var xml1:XML =
<trivia>
    <question>What is the difference between a duck?</question>
    <answer>I have no idea</answer>
</trivia>;

var xml2:XML =
<trivia>
    <question>2+2</question>
    <answer>4</answer>
</trivia>;


var xmlJoin:XML = <sheet></sheet>;


var i:XML;
for each(i in xml1)
{
    xmlJoin.appendChild(i);
}

for each(i in xml2)
{
    xmlJoin.appendChild(i);
}

trace(xmlJoin);
```

Comment: I think I understand what your going for but I'm pretty new to this xml stuff. I'll give this a try. Thanks.

Comment: I edited my code above to include your suggestion but now I'm getting two "access to undefined property" errors for myLoader and myLoader2 and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `appendChild()` method of an `XML` object like the following:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            var xml1:XML = <rootNode>
                               <parentNode>
                                   <childNode>1</childNode>
                                </parentNode>
                            </rootNode>;

            var xml2:XML = <rootNode>
                               <parentNode>
                                   <childNode>2</childNode>
                                </parentNode>
                            </rootNode>;

            xml1.parentNode.appendChild(xml2.parentNode.childNode);

            trace(xml1); // output: <rootNode>
                         //             <parentNode>
                         //                 <childNode>1</childNode>
                         //                 <childNode>2</childNode>
                         //             </parentNode>
                         //         </rootNode>

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

**[UPDATE]**

You can also simply merge both `XML` objects into an `XMLList` object like the following:

```
var xmlList:XMLList = XMLList(xml1.toString().concat(xml2.toString())); // XMLList(xml1 + xml2)

trace(xmlList); // output: <rootNode>
                //             <parentNode>
                //                 <childNode>1</childNode>
                //             </parentNode>
                //         </rootNode>
                //         <rootNode>
                //             <parentNode>
                //                 <childNode>2</childNode>
                //             </parentNode>
                //         </rootNode>
```

**[UPDATE 2]**

I rewrote your application(well the portion of your application you posted) to show you the approach you may want to take:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.SharedObject;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var _sharedObject:SharedObject;
        private var _urls:Array;
        private var _xmls:Vector.<XML>;
        private var _xmlsLoaded:int;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            _sharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("questions");
            _sharedObject.data.category = Category.BOTH;

            _xmls = new Vector.<XML>();

            switch(_sharedObject.data.category)
            {
                case Category.ONE:  loadXml("xml/category1.xml");                      break;
                case Category.TWO:  loadXml("xml/category2.xml");                      break;
                case Category.BOTH: loadXml("xml/category1.xml", "xml/category2.xml"); break;

            }// end switch

        }// end function

        private function loadXml(...urls):void
        {
            _urls = urls;

            for each(var url:String in urls)
            {
                var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest(url));
                urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onUrlLoaderComplete);

            }// end function

        }// end function

        private function onUrlLoaderComplete(e:Event):void
        {
            _xmls.push(XML(URLLoader(e.target).data));

            if (_urls.length == ++_xmlsLoaded) traceXMLList();

        }// end if

        private function traceXMLList():void
        {
            trace(getXMLList(_xmls)); // output: <category1>
                                      //             <question>question 1</question>
                                      //             <question>question 2</question>
                                      //         </category1>
                                      //         <category2>
                                      //             <question>question 1</question>
                                      //             <question>question 2</question>
                                      //         </category2>


        }// end function

        private function getXMLList(_xmls:Vector.<XML>):XMLList
        {
            var xmlList:XMLList = new XMLList();

            for (var i:uint = 0; i < _xmls.length; i++)
            xmlList += _xmls[i];

            return xmlList;

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package

internal class Category
{
    public static const ONE:String = "one";
    public static const TWO:String = "two";
    public static const BOTH:String = "both";

}// end class
```

Comment: Thanks. This isn't quite what I meant by merge though. I actually just need to append the questions from the second xml into the end first xml. I think I made this sound much harder that it is.

Comment: Maybe if you posted a sample of the xml your using, it would be easier to show you how exactly you would merge the xml. My answer shows how you can choose where you append children from one `XML` object to a specific axis in another `XML` object. Also I would reconsider the code your using in your application. There seems to be a lot of needless code and you would be better off using `switch` statements rather than `if` statements in my opinion. I'd rewrite the application for you but without knowing the structure of your xml(as well as knowing the other aspects of your application) I can't.