# How to concatenate XML from two service calls

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I have two service calls which cannot be combined for various reasons. I need to concatenate the xml data from the two before parsing it. I'm using AS3.

Call one returns:

```
<rootNode>
  <employees>
     <employee> 
       <lastname>Smith</lastname> 
       <firstname>Jean</firstname> 
     </employee>
     <employee> 
       <lastname>Hardy</lastname> 
       <firstname>James</firstname> 
     </employee>
  </employees>
</rootNode>
```

So I put this into an XML variable called publicContactsXML.

Call two returns a different dataset, but with the same structure:

```
<rootNode>
  <employees>
     <employee> 
       <lastname>Moss</lastname> 
       <firstname>Randy</firstname> 
     </employee>
     <employee> 
       <lastname>Tompkins</lastname> 
       <firstname>Rachel</firstname> 
     </employee>
     <employee> 
       <lastname>James</lastname> 
       <firstname>Marshall</firstname> 
     </employee>
  </employees>
</rootNode>
```

I put this into a variable called personalContactsXML. So what I'm trying to do is grab the list of employees from the second call, and insert it into the result of the first call (i.e. publicContactsXML) so that I end up with an XML object which includes all five employees, which I will then parse.

I can successfully grab the list of employees  this way:

```
var personalContactsXMLList:XMLList = personalContactsXML..employee;
```

But I cannot append the XMLList to the original XML object. I keep trying to convert back and forth between XML, XMLList, and XMLList.toXMLString(), without success.

Does someone know how to do this?

Comment: Already answered, just search Google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905410/as3-merging-xml-files

Comment: Andrey is right, the answers on that other question are good. Also, on that last line of code, did you mean to have two dots? I think `personalContactsXML..employee;` should be `personalContactsXML.employee;`

Comment: Hi guys, Yes, you're right (those results didn't come up for me when I googled.) I was able to do it by publicContactsXML.employees.appendChild(personalContactsXML.employees.employee). @Jason -- I was using the descendant accessor (..). Thanks. Not sure what protocol is here -- do I answer my own question or do you want to?

Comment: I'll answer so we both benefit (you get rep for accepting someone else's answer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andrey said, there are some good answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905410/as3-merging-xml-files). However, for the benefit of this particular question, I'll restate the answer from the comments.

To concatenate two XMLs, you need to use appendChild. As you mentioned, you can use `publicContactsXML.employees.appendChild(personalContactsXML.employees.employee)`. If my memory serves me correctly, this will concatenate the first one `employee` child.

However, if you want to add ALL of the children, you can do that using a loop.

```
for(var i:int = 0; personalContactsXML.employees.employee[i] != undefined; i++)
{
    publicContactsXML.employees.appendChild(personalContactsXML.employees.employee[i];
}
```

Basically, as long as the `employee` child at index `i` of `employees` exists (`!= undefined`), we add that child, and move on to the next.